# "read_shape" was not found

Tags: shapefile, r-sf, tmap

I have got a problem with reading my shapefile. The below code used to work properly but all of a sudden I got the below error. I reinstalled R, Rstudio, and all the related packages but none of them fixed the problem.
Thanks,
NM

```
    usshapefile <- "cb_2017_us_county_500k.shp"
usgeo <- read_shape(file=usshapefile, as.sf = TRUE)
```

Error in read_shape(file = usshapefile, as.sf = TRUE) :
could not find function "read_shape"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `read_shape()` is a function from an older version of `tmap`.

If you want an `sf` object from a shapefile, try using `read_sf()` from the `sf` package.

```
library(sf)

usshapefile <- "cb_2017_us_county_500k.shp"
usgeo <- read_sf(file=usshapefile)
```

If you've already updated your packages, you might want take a look at the reference pages for their respective functions too.

[sf reference](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/index.html)

[tmap functions pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/tmap.pdf)

[tmap reference](https://r-tmap.github.io/tmap/)